# How do I use my RPi3 to act as a wireless adapter to make a nintendo switch controller?

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, bluetooth, wireless-adapter

GOAL: to make a wireless nintendo switch controller

First steps, i want to be able to connect a keyboard to the Pi3 to use as a wireless keyboard ie. can connect to another computer or device and use as a regular keyboard. So connect keyboard to Pi3, then Pi3 wirelessly sends keyboard signals to computer. And was wondering how i could do that.

Then i want to be able to instead of a computer, send that signal to a switch instead and use it as a controller. i dont know how to do that either.
Ideally i want to make my Pi3 into an adapter that connects through bluetooth to my switch. Or alternatively i could buy an bluetooth adapter to plug into my switch(unsure if this is how it works, or what adapter to get).

I saw some dude use his electric drum kit as a switch controller while playing super smash brothers which was what inspired me. So if anyone knows how to do this or has any resources(things i could read) that could help me do this that would be awesome. I have very limited knowledge on computer systems as i have just started learning about it so i'm unsure about how possible this project is and haven't found much online about this either.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is by far to broad for the format of this site. One question could be to use the RasPi as wireless keyboard. I'm not shure but I think you will find already answers on this site. But what do you want to do with a keyboard connected to a switch? A switch does not work with ip addresses and I can't see what a keyboard could do there.